# Finding row wise sum of transpose of hv-convex binary matrix

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, restricted-complexity

I'm stuck on a problem involving the [Gale-Ryser Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale%E2%80%93Ryser_theorem). The problem's input gives me the row-wise sum of an hv-convex binary matrix(n*m).

```
e.g. I get {4,3,2,2,1} in the input. It's the row wise sum of the following matrix:

    1 1 1 1
    1 1 1 0
    1 1 0 0
    1 1 0 0
    1 0 0 0
```

To solve the problem, I have to find the row-wise sum of it's transpose.

```
i.e. I need to calculate {5,4,2,1}

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

Can it be achieved in less than O(n*m)?

---

**I got the answer [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110116/finding-row-wise-sum-of-transpose-of-hv-convex-binary-matrix).**

Comment: This might be more appropriate on cs.stackexchange.com, and you have already posted there. They'll ask you what you have already tried before giving hints to it.

Comment: This could probably still be somewhat salvageable as a challenge. Trivial for golfing languages but solutions in "real" languages could be interesting.